# curl hangs at no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end.With my http server

Tags: http, curl

I write a simple http server which now only can response 501.But when i test it. it shows

> Trying 127.0.0.1...    * TCP_NODELAY set   * Connected to localhost
>   (127.0.0.1) port 9999 (#0)
>
> > GET /bookstores/ HTTP/1.1
> >
> > Host: localhost:9999
> >
> > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> >
> > Accept: */*
> >
> > HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
> >
> > no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end

my response code looks like that:

```
#include "handle_client.h"
#include <string.h>
const char *crlf = "\r\n";
const char *sp =" ";
const char *http_version = "HTTP/1.1";
const char *status_code_501 = "501";
char* response_501(){
    char *reason_phase = "Not Implemented";
    char *status_line = (char *)calloc(4096, sizeof(char));
    strcat(status_line, http_version);
    strcat(status_line, sp);
    strcat(status_line, status_code_501);
    strcat(status_line, sp);
    strcat(status_line, reason_phase);
    strcat(status_line, crlf);
    strcat(status_line, crlf);
    return status_line;
}
```

Comment: See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length, point 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either close the connection or supply a content-length header field (set to zero). See RFC 7230, Section 3.3.3.

Comment: did it fix your problem?